# Custom trait propagation not working as expected outside of view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitraitcollection

I'm trying to build custom-styled components that can handle a custom trait propagated from above and adjust their styling accordingly. E.g.:

```swift
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)

      self.registerForTraitChanges([DangerStyleTrait.self]) { (self: Self, _) in
            // Do some styling changes if danger is true or not
      }
    }
}
```

I want to use these components inside others:

```swift
class InfoViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let button = CustomButton()
        view.addSubview(button)
        // <Button layout elided>
    }
}
```

In my usual scenario, the custom trait would be applied before presentation:

```swift
func showWarningAlert() {
    let viewController = InfoViewController
    viewController.traitOverrides.dangerStyleEnabled = true
    present(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

But the above does not work! The button never receives the trait change update and so the danger styling never gets applied. I would have assumed that as soon as the view controller's view gets added to the hierarchy, the update would get sent to the button.

If this is expected behaviour, is there a workaround for the above scenario? I would hope it is a reasonable use case to want to set up a whole view controller and then later apply a trait and have it propagate all the way down on presentation.

Thanks!

Comment: what is `self.registerForTraitChanges` doing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't specific to custom traits.

The trait isn't changing. It's there from the start. Your implementation of `CustomButton` should be checking its trait collection right from the start, in addition to checking for changes.

Whatever setup code is in your `CustomButton` class needs to take into account whatever traits affects its look right from the start.

Registering for a specific trait change is done to allow the view to update itself later if a trait changes.

Comment: This is basically correct; it will often be the case that the initial trait collection of a view (even before it's added to the hierarchy) will have the correct predicted value for your trait, so you won't see any change occur when it does get added to the hierarchy. But this is never guaranteed. This is why the recommendation is to use traits during layout (e.g. inside `layoutSubviews()`) which happens once the view is in the hierarchy (so you avoid reading the value too early when it's just a prediction), and then just call `setNeedsLayout()` inside the trait change handler to invalidate.